# Windows.UI.Xaml.Application vs DependencyObject

Tags: c++-winrt

Why `DependencyObject` has no user defined default constructor just like `Application`?

```
inline Application::Application()
{
    Windows::Foundation::IInspectable baseInterface, innerInterface;
    *this = impl::call_factory<Application, Windows::UI::Xaml::IApplicationFactory>([&](auto&& f) { return f.CreateInstance(baseInterface, innerInterface); });
}
```

I compared with their attributes : `Application` has following attributes

```
ComposableAttribute
ContractVersionAttribute
MarshalingBehaviorAttribute
StaticAttribute
ThreadingAttribute
WebHostHiddenAttribute
```

and `DependencyObject`

```
ComposableAttribute
ContractVersionAttribute
MarshalingBehaviorAttribute
ThreadingAttribute
WebHostHiddenAttribute
```

the only defference is the `StaticAttribute`, but I don't think this will convince me. Please help. Many thanks!!!

Comment: A `DependencyObject` serves as a base class. I can't think of a reason why you'd ever create an instance of that type. It's meant to be derived from, either by the Windows Runtime implementation or client code.

Comment: I‘m curious how cppwinrt.exe know that. Because it has no overridable interface？Sounds reasonable.

Comment: You can look inside the source code of [cppwinrt](https://github.com/microsoft/cppwinrt/tree/master/cppwinrt) to find hints. It's driven by .winmd files (found in `%WINDIR%\System32\WinMetadata`). You can inspect the .winmd files by opening them with *ildasm.exe* that ships as part of the .NET Framework.